# Is there a way to add a header in the middle of the rows in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a multiple columns in the grid, where the first row is the dropdown, and the second row is where i need to provide a header. Is there a way to provide a header in the middle of the rows.?

http://i44.tinypic.com/2qsx9ir.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Why not just put the dropdown outside/above the grid?